# Jenkins HTTP Request plugin authorization error for secret text

Tags: jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Http Request plugin in Jenkins to run HTTP Request towards an API.
I need to use a token for the authorization. So I configured on Jenkins global configuration a secret text credential with the token and gave it the id segron.
Then I run the API Call in Jenkins like this
`httpRequest url: "http://10.10.10.10:8080/api/run/", httpMode: 'POST', contentType:'APPLICATION_JSON',authentication: 'segron'`.

But when I run the pipeline I got this error.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication 'segron' doesn't exist anymore`
I use the same plugin to run other API Call using username / password as credentials, and it works perfectly fine.

Any help/experience regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case the Http Request plugin did not like the API-token stored as "secret text" in Jenkins.

After changing it to a username/password credential type it worked for me.

- username set to the user that owns the API-token
- password field gets the API-token from Bitbucket

This is a bit unexpected as Bitbucket related APIs like notfiyBitbucket worked perfectly fine with API-token in secret text credentials, but Http Request plugin does not seem to support that.
It does work the other way around though, notifyBitbucket also works with username/password credential type, so no need to store the API token twice now.

I assume this is the place where the exception is thrown: https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/http_request/HttpRequestExecution.java#L239
Looking at the lines above that, only a limited set of credential types seem to be supported. The exception should probably at least emit a more descriptive error message to understand what is wrong.